# Using RIPE's "-B" flag with the whois command

Tags: whois, flags

When using RIPE web DB search system, you can add the "-B" flag to list hidden attributes of an object.

I'm trying to find a way of adding the "-B" flag somewhere within the following command:

> ```
> > whois -h whois.ripe.net ASXXXXX
> ```

However, the whois program itself returns that it's not a valid flag.

I've tried echoing it in via stdin with no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a big fan of [GNU jwhois](http://www.gnu.org/software/jwhois/). It supports RIPE extensions and has many other options and is configurable beyond belief. You could use this command for your request:

```
jwhois -h whois.ripe.net -- -B ASXXX
```

Comment: The "--" option appears to work for BSD's whois command too :)

Answer (score 0):

`-B` is specific to RIPE so not supported in the generic client. Fortunately the whois protocol is exceptionally simple. This means you can telnet to port 43 on whois.ripe.net and type in the following:

`-B ASXXXXXX`

This will give you the output you're looking for.